# CasperJS - Cannot capture complete website screenshoot in withPopup function

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am new to CasperJS.

When I use `withPopup`, it seems like the page in the popup does not load completely...

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
})

casper.start('https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp').then(function(){
    this.capture('try1.png');
    this.click('#main p a');
})

casper.waitForPopup(0, function() {
    this.capture('try2.png');

}, null, 20000);

casper.withPopup(0, function() {
    this.waitForSelector('body', function(){
        this.capture('try3.png');
    })
});

casper.run(function() {
    casper.echo('Done.').exit();
});
```

Comment: For starters `#main p a` returns at least 290 anchors elements. Secondly clicking the first of these does not show a popup window but redirects to another url! What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I just want to try withPopup function, use click to redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the screenshot is not incomplete, when using withPopup function, its view size changed. So just add this.viewport(1600,1000) in withPopup function then the screenshot would looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not related to `withPopup` but to `click`. For some reason, clicks are not always handled properly by browser automation libraries like CasperJS. If I were you, I would try to find a workaround. With a simple `thenOpen`, the popup is loaded correctly...

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  viewportSize: {
    width: 1366,
    height: 768
  }
});

casper.start('https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp', function () {
  this.capture('try1.png');
});

casper.thenOpen('https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_inner_html', function () {
  this.capture('try2.png');
});

casper.run(function () {
  casper.echo('Done.').exit();
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to use click to redirect to another page? Thanks.